# How can I enable IPv6 when microk8s is already installed?

Tags: server, 23.04, ipv6, microk8s

I’ve read [this article](https://microk8s.io/docs/how-to-dual-stack) about enabling IPv6 on `microk8s` (which is a `snap`-package), but the documentation only talks about how to apply the configuration *before* you install `microk8s`; I installed it during the setup of my Ubuntu Server.

I’d like to know how to enable IPv6 *after* `microk8s` has been installed. The default installation settings work fine for me, so I don’t need to change anything except `IPv6_SUPPORT: true` (I don’t know if the parameters `IPv6_CLUSTER_CIDR` and `IPv6_SERVICE_CIDR` need to be included and manually configured or if they are automagically configured).

Comment: Read `man dpkg-reconfigure`, a tool to reconfigre an installed package.

Comment: @waltinator Should've pointed that `microk8s` is a Snap package. I've edited the post now.

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.